# SQL with asp classic

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm creating a website for my and am struggling with the SQL parts, below are two separate statements I am struggling with, if you know what could be the problem with any of them id appreciate it.

This is the statement

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE <%=GalleryRs ("img_USERID")%> = <%=session ("usr_ID")%>"
```

This is the error

> Expected end of statement
>
> /WIP/Gallery.asp, line 20
>
> readsql = "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE <%=GalleryRs ("img_USERID")
>       ------------------------------------------------------^

This is the second statement

```
INSERT INTO like (lik_POSTID) VALUES('" &_
request("pos_ID") & "')
```

and the error

> Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e14'
>
> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
>
> /student/S0190204/WIP/like.asp, line 56

If you can help with either one that would be grand, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE "& GalleryRs("img_USERID")&" = "& session("usr_ID")
```

<%= %> makes no sense within an asp code block.   It's for when you want to embed an asp variable within your html code - the "=" sign is shorthand for Response.Write - eg

```
<h1><%= pagetitle %></h1>
```

Also note that I've taken out the spaces after "GalleryRs" and "Session"

Edited

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE "& GalleryRs("img_USERID")&" = '"& session("usr_ID") & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks this got me further, although it says Type Mismatch now. Any idea what this means?

Comment: what's the value of GalleryRs("img_USERID") and session("usr_ID")?

Comment: Type mismatch usually happens when a number is expected and the page receives a string.  Try it with  "Cint(GalleryRs("img_USERID"))" and "Cint(session("usr_ID"))"

Comment: Shouldn't GalleryRS("img_USERID") be the name of a field? Then it can't be an integer.

Comment: usr_ID is '40' and img_USER_ID is also '40'. One is an 'autonumber' and the is just a 'number' in access, could that be causing a problem?

Comment: You could also try putting single quotes around your variable names.  I'll edit my answer

Comment: This would result in the query: 
SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE 40 = 40
This WHERE is always true and results in returning all records from Gallery table. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, a query along the lines of "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE ing_usrid = 40" (where 40 is the current value of Session("userid") )would make sense

Comment: no I'm trying to get it to display only the records containing the usr_ID in this case 40.

Comment: so probably: readsql = "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE usr_ID = " & CLng(session("usr_ID"))

Comment: I seem to be getting object required" now no matter what I put.

Comment: Try INSERT INTO like (lik_POSTID) VALUES ('" & request("pos_ID") & "') for your second query.  No need to break it over two lines

Comment: Does "object required" indicate a line in your code where the error is occurring?

Comment: is there a value in session("usr_ID") or request("pos_ID")?

Answer (score 0):

Your select sql should look like this when it gets to the database:

```
select *
from Gallery
where img_UserId = something
```

You are sending:

```
select * 
from Gallery
where <%= etc
```

Your field name does not include <%.  Look at why you are using a variable there.  Unless the field in your where clause is not the same everytime, don't use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE <%=GalleryRs ("img_USERID")%> = <%=session ("usr_ID")%>"
```

should be

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM Gallery WHERE " & GalleryRs("img_USERID") & " = " & session ("usr_ID")
```

I agree with Dan, why use a variable for your field name? Besides that, this code has a very high level of 'sql injection friendliness'. At least verify what the values in GalleryRs("img_USERID") and session ("usr_ID") are (convert to int or check length). Better is to move this to a stored procedure!